# Is it possible to transfer singleplayer progression between console generations in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Can I transfer singleplayer progression in GTA V on PS3 to PS4 and from Xbox 360 to Xbox One?

Comment: Related: [Can I transfer GTA V saves multiple times?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/253282/4797)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, **no**. The official answer on [this support question](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201411813-PS3-Single-Player-Data-To-PS4-) suggests that such functionality may be provided in the future.