# Can I transfer a game from a friends PSN account to mine?

Tags: psn

My friend gave me his email and password to log in to his account, but it says I can only log into one account, via PlayStation Network.

If he logs in to my account, can he transfer Grand Theft Auto V from his PSN account to mine?

Comment: Going to point out the obvious, here, but its complaining because your already signed in to your account. If you sign out of your account, there will be no immediate problem, but what your suggesting has the potential to open up other potential issues.

Comment: Someone might elaborate for me, but if your friend logs into his account on your playstation, he can register your console as his "primary". This should allow you to play **his** games from **your** account. This should be a more legitimate solution, but may conflict with your friends wishes, if he intends to continue using his PSN account.

Comment: so he's trouble changing his account back to his primary and now he's stuck with mine. how would game sharing work? would it work for gta v?

Comment: You can onlybe signed in to one account at one time. Before you sign in to account B, you must first sign out of account A. If he signs in to his account, and marks your playstation as his primary, you get access to all his paid services. This includes games, and i think PS Plus. You can still access this from your account, presuming your on the cobsole he has marked as his primary. Again, its not intended for that use, so Im not sure what sony will do if they detect what your doing. Him constantly logging into the account from a differant internet address may completely void it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to transfer singleplayer progression between console generations in GTA V?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192300/is-it-possible-to-transfer-singleplayer-progression-between-console-generations)

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, when you purchase a game you are purchasing the rights for that game. **There is no allowance for transferring the game to another account.** Furthermore, **accessing another users PSN account is against terms of service** as much as deliberately providing another user with your account details is. You have a better chance of both your accounts being blocked, either temporarily, or permanently.

If your friend made a mistake purchasing Grand Theft Auto V, there is a possibility that Sony will offer an alternate solution. That said, if he has already played it, this is quite unlikely.