# Can I transfer GTA V saves multiple times?

Tags: ps3, ps4, grand-theft-auto-online, rockstar-games-social-club

I have a ps4, but it reset. I want to transfer my saved GTA 5 data from a ps3 to a ps4. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to transfer singleplayer progression between console generations in GTA V?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/192300/4797)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Rockstar support page regarding the transfer](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC):

> You can only transfer a set of character and progression data from PlayStation®3 or Xbox 360 once.

However, as far as I know, the saved data of the online part of GTA is not saved locally, but on the Rockstar servers, so you should still be able to load your old online save as long as you are on the same PSN and Social Club profile.